# Automagically upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 32bit to 12.10 64bit

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I'm looking for a little advice, I would like to do an upgrade preferably through the update manager from my current 10.10 32bit Ubuntu Box, to 12.04 64bit, can anyone think of anyway I could do this without doing a full re-install of my linux partition?

My reckoning is even if I tell the update manager to just goahead and do it, it will install 12.04 32bit

any advice?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You are almost certainly going to have to do a clean install. I would also suggest you go for 14.04 which is also a long term support release.

Comment: Unfortunately that is kind of what i was thinking oh well thanks for your advice :)

Comment: An upgrade across multiple versions is generally not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, 'yes' you can do this. It's not really a great idea and there's no way I know of at least do this 'automatically' or through update manager. It will be cleaner and less of a headache in the end to just do a clean install, go 14.04 as mentioned above also.

[Here's a link to a previously answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation). It does have a walk through, but you'll have to drop into command line to do this.

Comment: While I believe it be worthwhile to get a USB stick with sufficient capacity to move over the existing installation in case the upgrade fails, it would also allow for a fresh installation with probably less hassle. Having said that, the above link and links therein do not seem to point to the a ready step-by-step guide to actually perform a 32bit to 64bit system upgrade. The following worked for me: [http://www.ewan.cc/?q=node/132](http://www.ewan.cc/?q=node/132). Then again, the original poster asked for a solution from back when Ubuntu did not have the MultiArch specification implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I would backup your personal files, and proceed with 14.04 lts 64bit like others have suggested.

If you're considering 12.x because you have limited system resources, there are other options:

[Lubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu) is a lightweight flavor of Ubuntu keeping older spec machines in mind.

[Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/) is another Linux, not Ubuntu-based, but focuses on ease-of-use and minimal system resource requirements.